# Association for membership join model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models

```
Class User
  has_many :memberships

Class Membership
  belongs_to :user
```

The membership table has two columns, `user_id` and `organization_id`.
However the `organization_id` is also a user id.

How can I specificy an association so that:

`@user.organizations` returns a list of organizations(other users) of which this user is a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization, class_name: "User"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct way of doing this would be to create three models as follows:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_one :organization
end

#organization.rb
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :memberships
end

#membership.rb
class Membership  < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :organization_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end
```